# Cannot detect animation end

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to listen for when an animation ends so that I can hide the element upon completion but the listener doesn't seem to be firing... what am I doing wrong?

JavaScript

```
angular.module('webApp')
  .controller('MainController', function ($window) {
    vm.loader = document.getElementById('loader');

    angular.element($window).bind('load', function() {
      vm.loader.style.opacity = 0;
    });

    vm.loader.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function(){
      vm.loader.style.display = 'none';
    }, false);
  });
```

HTML

```
  <div id="loader" ng-init='load()'>
    <div class="loader">
      <div class="position-center-center"> 
        <img src="images/shared/logo.svg" id="loader-img">
        <p class="font-playfair text-center">Please Wait...</p>
        <div class="loading">
          <div class="ball"></div>
          <div class="ball"></div>
          <div class="ball"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.ball {
    background: #000 !important;
}
#loader {
  opacity:1;
  transition: opacity 1s;  
  transition-delay: 2s;  
}
#loader-img {
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`webkitAnimationEnd` is not the right event to detect **transitions** you need to use the appropriate event: `webkitTransitionEnd` `otransitionend` `oTransitionEnd` `msTransitionEnd` `transitionend`

From MDN.

> The transitionend event is fired when a CSS transition has completed. In the case where a transition is removed before completion, such as if the transition-property is removed or display is set to "none", then the event will not be generated.